# Google OR-Tools time-window constraints solving slowly

Tags: python, or-tools

I am testing using OR-Tools to solve a VRPTW, and it is taking longer than desired to solve.

I am using the sample code given here (https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw), but slightly modified:

```
    data['time_windows'] = [
        (0, 999),  # depot
        (0, 20),  # 1
        (0, 999),  # 2
        (0, 999),  # 3
        (0, 999),  # 4
        (0, 999),  # 5
        (0, 999),  # 6
        (0, 999),  # 7
        (0, 999),  # 8
        (0, 999),  # 9
        (0, 999),  # 10
        (0, 999),  # 11
        (0, 999),  # 12
        (0, 999),  # 13
        (0, 999),  # 14
        (0, 999),  # 15
        (0, 999),  # 16
    ]
    data['num_vehicles'] = 1
```

And

```
    routing.AddDimension(
        transit_callback_index,
        999,  # allow waiting time
        999,  # maximum time per vehicle
        False,  # Don't force start cumul to zero.
        time)
```

I am trying to model finding the best route with just one constraint, that location #1 must be visited between 0 and 20.

This takes 22.6 seconds to solve on my computer, which seems a little long to me. I have tried adjusting the FirstSolutionStrategy to various other ones, but they either take similarly long to solve, or fail to solve it entirely when I make the constraint tighter.

Making the window even tighter to (0, 6) takes even longer to solve.

Also, strangely, reducing the window for all other nodes from (0, 999) to (0, 50) significantly reduces calculation time to 1.8 seconds, but does not affect the output at all.

This is one step away from being a simple TSP, but takes significantly longer to solve, and I am wondering if I did something wrong.